# ADF Mapping Dataflow Temp Table issue inside SP call

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-synapse, azure-mapping-data-flow

I have a mapping dataflow inside a foreach activity which I'm using to copy several tables into ADLS; in the dataflow source activity, I call a stored procedure from my synapse environment.  In the SP, I have a small temp table which I create to store some values which I will later use for processing a query.

When I run the pipeline, I get an error on the mapping dataflow; "SQLServerException: 111212: Operation cannot be performed within a transaction."  If I remove the temp table, and just do a simple select * from a small table, it returns the data fine; it's only after I bring back the temp table that I get an issue.

Have you guys ever seen this before, and is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after running some tests around this issue, it seems like Mapping Dataflows do not like Temp Tables when I call my stored procedure.

The way I ended up fixing this was that instead of using a Temp Table, I ended up using a CTE, which believe it or not, runs a bit faster than when I used the Temp Table.

@KarthikBhyresh

I looked at that article before, but it wasn't an issue with the sink, I was using Synapse LS as my source and a Data Lake Storage as my sink, so I knew from the beginning that this did not apply to my issue, even though it was the same error number.

Answer (score 2):

If you go through the **official MS docs**, this error is very well documented.

[Failed with an error: "SQLServerException: 111212; Operation cannot be performed within a transaction."](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-troubleshoot-connector-format#failed-with-an-error-sqlserverexception-111212-operation-cannot-be-performed-within-a-transaction)

> ##### Symptoms
>
> When you use the Azure SQL Database as a sink in the data flow to
> preview data, debug/trigger run and do other activities, you may find
> your job fails with following error message:
>
> `{"StatusCode":"DFExecutorUserError","Message":"Job failed due to reason: at Sink 'sink': shaded.msdataflow.com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: 111212;Operation cannot be performed within a transaction.","Details":"at Sink 'sink': shaded.msdataflow.com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: 111212;Operation cannot be performed within a transaction."}`
>
> ##### Cause
>
> The error "`111212;Operation cannot be performed within a transaction.`" only occurs in the Synapse dedicated SQL pool. But you
> mistakenly use the Azure SQL Database as the connector instead.
>
> ##### Recommendation
>
> Confirm if your SQL Database is a Synapse dedicated SQL pool. If so,
> use Azure Synapse Analytics as a connector shown in the picture below.
>
> [image: Screenshot that shows the Azure Synapse Analytics connector.]